# Just a Simple Number Crossword

Tags: mathematics, cipher, crosswords

I made a small number crossword for my mathletes club that I thought I'd share.  It's not too hard, I think it's just right for a coffee break.  Have fun!

(Edit:  No answer has a leading zero)

[image: crossword]

Comment: Is the last across clue intended to be enigmatic? And isn't 4A true of every integer?

Comment: @noedne How is (e.g.) 3 divisible by two distinct perfect cubes?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain $1^3$ and $(-1)^3$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when discussing divisibility, it is generally assumed that one is dealing only with positive integers.

Comment: @noedne yes, I only want positive factors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numerical answer is

> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline 7 & 1 & 8 \\ \hline 1 & 3 & 5 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

My thinking went something like this:

> **3D** means that the second digit of 1D must be a $1$, because any number 20 or larger multiplied by 5 would end up as 3 digits. (It can't be a 0 because leading 0s aren't allowed for **4A**.)
>
> Since 1 is reversible on a 7-segment display, the other digit of **1D** must not be.  The only digits that don't form a digit when turned upside down are 3, 4, and 7.  Thus **3D** must be $65$, $70$, or $85$.
>
> For **4A**, we now have a first digit of $1$, and a last digit of $5$ or $0$.  The middle digit must be odd, because **2D** is prime, and no 2-digit prime is even.  This makes the number of possibilities for **4A** very small.  By a little trial and error (multiplying 8, 27, 64), it easy to discover that the only possible solution is $135$, which is a multiple of both $1^3$ and $3^3$.
>
> Now we have that **1A** is either $3x6$ or $7x8$ (where $x$ is the unknown digit). Since two of the digits must sum to the third, the only possibilities are $336$, $396$, or $718$.  The first two options do not make **2D** prime (33 and 93 are both composite), so the solution for **1A** must be $718$, making **2D** $13$.

The final answer (thanks to [PiIsNot3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57742/piisnot3), [below](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83212/just-a-simple-number-crossword/83214#comment241472_83214)), is found by

> using A1Z26 to translate each number into a letter.  The dotted line indicates that those two digits should be treated as a single number.
>  Thus we have 7-18-1-3-5, which translates to
>
>   **GRACE**

Comment: This is the correct numerical answer.

Comment: Notice that the line separating 2 and 3 is dotted, meaning that the 1 and 8 should be read together as 18. Doing A1Z26 gives rot13(TENPR), which is the “elegant name.”

Comment: I have added an explanation and the final answer, as supplied by @PiIsNot3.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking strictly, there is another (numerical) solution:

> 145 
>  135

That's because

> On a 7-segment indicator, an upside-down 1 is *not* the same that the "original" 1.

Comment: There is no such requirement in the puzzle.

Comment: You are technically right, that clue may be somewhat vague.  In spirit, what I wanted to get at was the fact that numbers such as 219, 6901, 55, etc. can be cleanly read as numbers when turned upside-down, especially when entered into a 7-segment display.  However, I will argue here that even an "11" would still technically represent a base 10 numeral, even though the placement of the ones don't follow the standard convention.  The same cannot be argued for numbers such as 3, 4, or 7, and assigning values to "E", "h", or "L" seems a bit of a stretch, so I think we're in the clear here.